# React native rotation transformations break flex box layout

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flexbox

I want to make a slider vertical on ios. I have a component that looks like this, the text labels are just for visualisation

```
export class VerticalSlider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
        <Slider
          maximumValue={100}
          minimumValue={0}
          value={50}
          minimumTrackTintColor="black"
          style={{
            transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }]
          }}
        />
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>

    )
  }
}
```

This is how it looks in my simulator

[image]

It looks like flex box lays out the components before the rotation, then it gets rotated 90 degrees and it overlaps with the text labels above and below. I would expect the top of the slider to be at the bottom of the first label and the second label to be pushed down.

Is there something i can do to fix this?

Here are my versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^29.0.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.gz"
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I undestand it correctly, you want something like this, right (don't pay attention to the title and the cross) ?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIVjm.jpg)

If it's what you want, you just have to wrap your components in a view with a flex:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Slider
            maximumValue={100}
            minimumValue={0}
            value={50}
            minimumTrackTintColor="black"
            style={{transform: [{rotate: '90deg'}]}} />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

*Edit (explanation) :*

A flexbox is basically an area. In this area, all the Subarea will take some space according to their flex property.

If you have a 3 sub - area where the flex property is set to 1, the 3 will take the space space:

[ 1 | 2 | 3 ]

If you have a 3 sub - area where the flex property is set to 1, 1 and 2, the total area will have a size of 4 flex:

[ 1 | 2 | 3 3 ]

I don't know if it's clear, but you can check this link. It's basically the same with React Native, except that you don't need to display your view as Flex :)

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

In your code, even if your `<View>` is a flexbox with a flex set to 1, your `<Text>` and `<Slider>` are not flexible components, so there is nothing saying that they have to take 1/3 (each) of the total space. By wrapping them in a `View style={{flex: 1}}>` we are just setting this and ta-da

Comment: nice that works, could you explain a little as to what was wrong, im still grokking flexbox

Comment: I just added some explaination, my english is not perfect, but I hope it's helping !